# Fugitive: jump from diff to the current version

Tags: key-bindings, git, plugin-fugitive

When exploring a commit using `:Gedit HEAD`, when I click `o` or `Enter` into the change, it shows me a `vimdiff` of the two file versions of the change.

From there I often need to jump to the current version of the file in the filesystem

I wonder if there is any idiomatic way to move from a diff of two versions of the file to its current version.

Comment: What precisely should happen? Close both splits of the diff, or leave them open and open a new split with the current state, or something else...? Please [edit]. (You may be interested in `:Gedit` and it's splitting relatives `:Gsplit`/`:Gvsplit`)

Comment: I should have made it more clear the question is when exploring a commit not the current `staged` or not changes such as with `Git status`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `:h :diffoff` which removes diff options of the two buffers of a two-way diff.

This is mapped to `dq` in Fugitive.

You can go back to diff mode with Fugitive's `Gdiffsplit`.

---

Besides, the default for <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `o` in Fugitive's status window is to open the current version of the file, while <kbd>dd</kbd> is supposed to show the two-way diff.

I think you tweaked this, but the default might better suit your needs.

Comment: OP is exploring a commit, not just the regular status, so I could see o/enter opening a diff. Subtle and easy to miss though! Partly why I asked for clarification

Comment: Oh. I get it now. My answer is totally beside the point.

Comment: Nah, it could be useful to someone else; my vote would ve leave it up!

Comment: I just tried to downvote it (so people would see it's not very useful) but couldn't ;( GG for 10k! @D.BenKnoble

Comment: this answer helped, the fastest way I found so far is: `dq` to quit the diff and then `Gedit` to open the current version.